# How to keep AppBar at the top of the screen

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to prevent the `appBar` from remaining fixed on the top of the screen? I want the `appBar` to be static at the top of the screen, and be able to scroll it out of view.

For example, if there's a long list you wouldn't see the `appBar` always at the top of the screen when scrolling down the list.

```
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(..)
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) in CustomScrollView. There is a parameter **pinned** in **SliverAppBar** widget, which you can play around with it to achieve your desired output.

Happy Fluttering!